# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un link activo en la paginación de Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Yo modifico con CSS algunos valores, pero el color de fondo del active link no lo logro cambiar.

Este código está acá en StackOverFlow:

```
.pagination > li > a
{
background-color: white;
color: purple;
}

.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:focus,
.pagination > li > span:hover
{
    color: purple;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-color: #ddd;
}

.pagination > .active > a
{
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    border: solid 1px purple;
}

.pagination > .active > a:hover
{
    background-color: purple;
    border: solid 1px purple;
}
```

No me funciona este:

```
.pagination > .active > a
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el trocito del html? Solo con el css es difícil saber si es un error en el selector o en otra parte

Comment: Así de primeras te diría que probases a ponerle !important al cambio de color que no te está funcionando. **background-color: purple !important;**. Sin ver el HTML que tienes montado para el paginador lo demás sería dar palos de ciego.

Comment: Intenta con .page-item.active .page-link {   
    background-color: pink !important;
    border-color: pink !important;
}

Comment: Proba poniendole !important al css ya que esos botones tienen clases y la tuya tendria que ser la principal pisando la de bootstrap

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, intenté todo y me funcionó la solución de Dariel Ramos

Answer (score 0):

Entra aquí [REFERENCIA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355009/changing-pagination-colour-bootstrap)
Te falta seleccionar el *li* de otra manera entenderá mal el CSS

```css
.example .pagination>li>a,
.example .pagination>li>span {
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.pagination>li.active>a {
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="example">
    <nav>
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled">
          <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles, explicar qué cambios has hecho y por qué o cómo solucionan el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.